# Does the 'upload_to' callback in the FileField hit the db for related content?

Tags: django, database, django-orm

I have an `Attachment` model with two ForeignKey fields and a `get_attachment_path` callback for the `upload_to` attribute:

```py
def get_attachment_path(instance, filename):
    return f'{instance.owner.name}/{instance.chat.id}/{filename}'

class Attachment(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(..)
    chat = models.ForeignKey(..)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_attachment_path, ...)
```

Below line will cause the `get_attachment_path` run:

```
Attachment.objects.create(..., file=file)
```

So, with the line above, will django hit the db twice (one for the `.create` and one another for the `get_attachment_path`)? Asking it because the `get_attachment_path` callback tries to access related data (`instance.chat.id` etc.).

If so, is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: Yes, it wil hit the database to fetch the `owner` and the `chat` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not hit the DB, because you're already passing existing and saved(!) `Owner` and `Chat` objects to `Attachment.objects.create`, so the upload handler does not need to fetch them from the database.

However, extra queries for related objects will be made when you get the attachment fresh from the database:

```
attachment = Attachment.objects.get(id=some_id)
attachment.file.save(...)
```

In this case using [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) can remove the extra queries.

You can always verify the SQL queries that are run (only in `DEBUG` mode):

```py
from django.db import connection

def get_attachment_path(instance, filename):
    print('Queries before', connection.queries)
    path = f'{instance.owner.name}/{instance.chat.id}/{filename}'
    print('Queries after', connection.queries)
    return path
```

Alternatively, [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a great addition to a Django project to optimize SQL queries.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer.